# Can multiple identity providers be configured for azure-active-directory-spring-boot-starter?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, azure-active-directory

For *azure-active-directory-spring-boot-starter* is it possible to specify multiple identity providers in Spring Boot's *application.properties*, similiar to how multiple identity providers can be configured for Spring Security's SAML functionality? I have only seen examples of configuring a single identity provider:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure.client-id=xxxxxx-your-client-id-xxxxxx
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure.client-secret=xxxxxx-your-client-secret-xxxxxx
azure.activedirectory.tenant-id=xxxxxx-your-tenant-id-xxxxxx
azure.activedirectory.user-group.allowed-groups=group1, group2
```

Comment: If you want to use  multiple identity providers, I suggest you use Azure AD B2C: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiC2bnJhIHrAhURfnAKHaB3CzoQFjAAegQIBRAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fdeveloper%2Fjava%2Fspring-framework%2Fconfigure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-active-directory-b2c-oidc&usg=AOvVaw0ULrdQZKowRvhzZWZ0VdJU

Answer (score 0):

You can use azure ad b2c for multiple identity provider usage.
There is a official documentation which explaining how to configure spring boot starter-java app with azure ad b2c.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-active-directory-b2c-oidc

Comment: So the multiple identity providers are specified in my local Azure instance rather than within my Spring Boot application? And then my application just needs to specify that local Azure instance as its single identity provider and the latter will take care of delegating to the appropriate identity provider?

Comment: Azure Active Directory B2C provides business-to-customer identity as a service. Your customers use their preferred social, enterprise, or local account identities to get single sign-on access to your applications and APIs. Please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/overview) for clear understanding on B2C